# Can't figure out the function for filling array with random numbers c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

So I am trying to make a function randBetween that is going to generate random numbers and after fill the array with those numbers

Problem that I missing out on something when I try to move a statement into function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
using namespace std;

void fillArray(int arr[], int size, int min, int max);
int randBetween(int max, int min);
void printArray(int arr[], int size);
const int size = 10;

int main()
{
    int arr[size];
    
    int min = -100;
    int max = 100;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    fillArray(arr, size, min, max);
    printArray(arr, size);
    
}

int randBetween(int max, int min)
{
    
    int num = (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return num;
}

void fillArray(int arr[], int size, int min, int max)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        
        int num = 0;
        
        randBetween(min, max);
        //num = ( rand () % (max - min + 1)) + min;
        
        arr[i] = num;
        
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        cout << arr[count] << "\n";
    }
}
```

if I don't comment out   //num = ( rand () % (max - min + 1)) + min; it works perfect without function
however I must use it in the functions and I cant figure out what I do wrong;
I tried to change parameters, change location but nothing helps

Comment: `num = randBetween( min, max);`

Comment: Why are you using 20+ years old API when we have `<random>`?

Comment: 'cause i am a student and that's how they teach us

Comment: @kholostovamk Fair enough, but it's sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `num = ( rand () % (max - min + 1)) + min;` with `randBetween(min, max);` is missing something crucial: You aren't setting the `num` variable in the second case. Although you do set `num` inside the `randBetween` function, this is actually not the same variable; it's defined inside `randBetween`, so it's not reachable outside of it, and doesn't effect the `num` inside `fillArray`. You can fix this by setting the outer `num` using this line:

```
num = randBetween(min, max);
```

instead of just `randBetween(min, max);`.